# Changing language app programmatically, android studio JAVA

Tags: java, android

I've been stuck for a long time trying to change the entire language of my Java application. Everything seems to work fine if I try to change the language through a Spinner. The problem that is plaguing me is that I can no longer switch languages when I publish my app on the play store! I can't figure out where the problem is and why it should apparently work when I test and then it doesn't work anymore when I publish it. When I select a language from the Spinner, the activity is recreated but the language is not set.

**BaseActivity, every activities extendes this:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
    }
}
```

**LocaleHelper.class**

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

**SignupActivity.class, where users can choose the language**

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static String[] languages;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase));
    }

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Spinner languageSpinner = findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);

        languages = new String[]{getString(R.string.select_language_spinner), getString(R.string.english), getString(R.string.italian)};
        // Adattatore per il Spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        languageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        languageSpinner.setSelection(0);


        languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(SignupActivity.this, "en");
                        context.getResources();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(SignupActivity.this, "it");
                        context.getResources();
                        Intent intent_it = getIntent();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent_it);
                        break;
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
-keep class com.ggcreator.connect.activities.BaseActivity {*;}
-keep class android.content.res.Resources$Theme {
  void rebase();
}
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
    resConfigs ("it", "en")
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
 android:configChanges="locale"
```

**Every attempt to remedy the problem has always brought me back to this:
**

```
2024-02-25 12:08:20.860 399-399/com.ggcreator.connect I/ResourcesCompat: Failed to retrieve rebase() method
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: rebase []
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$ThemeCompat$Api23Impl.rebase(ResourcesCompat.java:788)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$ThemeCompat.rebase(ResourcesCompat.java:756)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachBaseContext2(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:522)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at com.ggcreator.connect.activities.BaseActivity.attachBaseContext(BaseActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7364)
```

Thank you for any possible help!